# Determine function value, given inequalities

Tags: functions, inequality

For each real number $r$ there is a real number $g(r)$. Moreover, it is known that for all real numbers $r$ and $s$ the inequalities $g(r) \leq r$ and $g(r+s)\leq g(r) + g(s)$ hold.

Determine $g(200)$.

Comment: Looks like $g$ is the absolute value function. This fits the triangle inequality.

Comment: @NoChance Note that it is $g(r)\le r$ and $r$ can be negative.

Comment: @mfl, good point. Thx.

Comment: Note that $g(r)=r$. Simply compute the derivative.

Comment: I'm not convinced $g(r) =r$

Comment: @RingoM what is wrong with g(r)=r?

Comment: @NoChance Seems too simple as the question is from a competition styled paper. I'm wondering if the question meant to find bounds on g(200).

Comment: @RingoM It was simply an information. Your question was in fact completely trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From $g(r+s)\le g(r)+g(s)$ we get that $$g(0)=g(0+0)\le g(0)+g(0)=2g(0).$$ So we have that $g(0)\ge 0.$ On the other hand, from $g(r)\le r$ it is $g(0)\le 0.$ Thus, we have shown that $g(0)=0.$

Now, assume that there exist $r$ such that $g(r)<r.$ In such a case we get

$$0=g(0)=g(r+(-r))\le g(r)+g(-r)\underbrace{<}_{g(r)<r}r+(-r)=0,$$ which contradicts $g(0)=0.$ So, for any $r$ it is $g(r)\ge r.$ This shows that $g(r)=r$ for any $r.$

In particular, $g(200)=200.$

Comment: Thanks @mfl this is a nice proof! I think a proof was what the question paper was expecting, more than just an answer.